# Excel VBA: Autofilter with multiple criteria, only filtering by last entry in array

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I am trying to do an autofilter based on numbers.  I can search the column for matches by converting to a string, but for filtering that gets trickier.

I have set the code so if the column to filter is numbers, it loops through them and adds any that contain "xxx" into an array (first instance of each).  I then use this array as the criteria for my autofilter.

The problem comes from the autofilter command.  If I use just the array for the criteria, it only filters by the last item in the array.  If I add the xlFilterValues as an operator, I get no results.

How do I properly make an array (variable) work as a criteria?  I have tried advanced filter as well, but was getting runtime errors.

Thanks

Relevant code:

```
If isInCol Then ' filter the table by the selected col; Use Range Sort
    With ActiveSheet
        If sortField = 10 Or sortField = 21 Then ' sort by a searched array
            ' sort through values, add matching to array
            For Each foo In filterColumn
                If InStr(CStr(foo.Value), filterText) Then
                    If arrayCounter = 0 Then
                        sortKeyNum(arrayCounter) = CDbl(foo.Value)
                        arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    ElseIf foo.Value <> sortKeyNum(arrayCounter - 1) Then
                        sortKeyNum(arrayCounter) = CDbl(foo.Value)
                        arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next foo
            ReDim Preserve sortKeyNum(arrayCounter - 1)
            currentData.AutoFilter Field:=sortField, Criteria1:=sortKeyNum, Operator:=xlFilterValues ' , VisibleDropDown:=False
            ' NOTE: ^^^^THIS IS WHERE MY CODE IS FAILING^^^^
        Else
            currentData.AutoFilter Field:=sortField, Criteria1:=sortKey ' , VisibleDropDown:=False
        End If
        currentData.Sort key1:=filterColumn, Order1:=sortOrder, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found [this](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154212-VBA-AutoFilter-with-array-Criteria).

Apparently when using an array to autofilter a column, it has to be in string format even if you're filtering numbers.  I changed the sortKeyNum to an array of strings, and it works as expected.